# Quero consultar várias palavras de forma independente no mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Bom dia tenho um input que gera uma variavel $frase com o dado dele.

$frase = "%".$frase."%";

No Mysql do php eu consulto o sql:

```
$comandoSql = select id from items where descricao like ?;

$stmt = $conexao->prepare($comandoSql) or trigger_error("triggererror ".$conexao->error);
$stmt->bind_param('s',$frase);
$stmt->execute()
```

Se eu digitar "fonte notebook",
Vai procurar "%fonte notebook%"

Eu quero que, quando eu digite "fonte notebook", 
Procure por:
"%fonte%" and "%notebook%"

Se for necessário eu tiro os bind_params, sei que teria que explodir e separar num vetor, aceito este código também, reformulando minha consulta sql e tirando o bind_params.

Mas se tiver como usar o bind, seria melhor.

Tem como por bind_params ?

Se não tem, qual o código de explodir variável mesmo e o que coloco para fechar o comandoSql ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta este código, fiz rapidinho mas é +- por aí..

```
<?php
$comandoSql = "select id from items where descricao" ;

$fraseAux = split(" ", str_replace('%', '', $frase));
for($i = 0; i < sizeOf($fraseAux); $i++){
    $comandoSql .= "like ?";
    if($i < sizeOf($fraseAux)){
        $comandoSql .= " OR ";
    }
}

$stmt = $conexao->prepare($comandoSql) or trigger_error("triggererror ".$conexao->error);

for($i = 0; i < sizeOf($fraseAux); $i++){
    $stmt->bind_param('s', '%'.$fraseAux[$i].'%');
}

$stmt->execute()
```